# Find out different lengths with values in a two-dimensional list, depending on the number given as a parameter

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose I have a two-dimensional list mixed with True and False. I would like to create a function that gives me an additional parameter, which should be the number of elements to be output. The output should be like this:
For example, if I enter `3` as a number, the row and column in which 3 x True are located one after the other should be displayed.
So just the row and the first column
For example, in the list below:
`3 x True in row: 1 and col: 3`

```
lst = [[False, True, False, True, True, False],
        [False, True, False, True, True, True],
        [True, False, True, True, True]]
```

I've tried several options, but never found a solution. I have another small example here, but of course I get the wrong output:

```
def baz(count):
    for row in range(len(lst)):
        for col in range(len(lst[row])):
            if lst[row][col] == lst[row][(col + count) % len(lst[row])] and lst[row][col] is True:
                return (row, col)


print(baz(3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to simplify the code, it returns `True` if all values in the iterable are `True` otherwise `False`.

```
lst = [[False, True, False, True, True, False],
        [False, True, False, True, True, True],
        [True, False, True, True, True]]

def baz(count):
    for row in range(len(lst)):
        if len(lst[row]) < count:
            continue
        for col in range(len(lst[row])-count+1):
            if all(lst[row][col:col+count]):
                return (row, col)
    return None


print(baz(3))
print(baz(2))
```

prints -

```
(1, 3)
(0, 3)
```

Note that there can be multiple matches for a given `count`, so the function returns the first match found.

Also, for high values of `count`, above code is not optimal(since in each step we are doing `O(count)` work when we call `all()`. So in case you are worried about performance you can use the below function instead -

```
def baz(count):
    for row in range(len(lst)):
        if len(lst[row]) < count:
            continue
        prev_true = -1
        for col in range(len(lst[row])):
            if not lst[row][col]:
                prev_true = col
                continue
            if col - prev_true == count:
                return (row, col-count+1)
    return None
```

Comment: Yes, but the answer is very good. I just wanted the first match. thank you